# How to get the select value from the html to controller

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html part

```
<select style="width:250px; height:50px">
                          <option ng-model="sellerDetails"  ng-click="sellerValue(sellerDetails)" >seller 1</option>
                          <option >seller 2</option>
                          <option >seller 3</option>
                        </select>
```

here is my controller part

```
 $scope.sellerValue= function(sellerDetails){
    console.log("invoking sellerValue");
    console.log(sellerDetails);
  }
```

what is wrong i am doing here 
i am not even invoking the controller part of my sellervalue funtion

Comment: Hmm, why do you bind ng-model on your option and not on select? I don't quite see what happends, but it's a weird construction.

Comment: you wrongly used the ng-model, plz refer to the ng docs    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: i have  3 options i need to get that seller option from view to controller so that i can get the array of index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some points:

**Point 1:** You've placed the `ngModel` in `<option>`, while it should be in `<select>` `tag`.

**Point 2:** `ngClick` is used to trigger, obviously `click`, it isn't the correct directive that you should use in this case, because a `click` doesn't mean that you changed the `value` of that field. The correct one is [**`ngChange`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) that detects real **changes**.

**Point 3:** Since you already have the value of selected item stored in `$scope.sellerDetails` you don't need to pass it as *parameter* to your function.

**Point 4:** I recommend you to use [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead of doing it `statically`.

See it *working*:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

  function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.sellers = [];
    
    function loadSellers(max) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        $scope.sellers.push("Seller " + i);
      }          
    }

    loadSellers(3);
    
    $scope.sellerValue = function() {
      console.log("sellerValue: ", $scope.sellerDetails);
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.select-field {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  Statically:
  <select class="select-field" ng-model="sellerDetails" ng-change="sellerValue()">
    <option>seller 1</option>
    <option>seller 2</option>
    <option>seller 3</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  With ng-options:
  <select class="select-field" ng-options="seller for seller in sellers" ng-model="sellerDetails" ng-change="sellerValue()">
    <option value="" disabled hidden>Select a seller</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sellerDetails = 'seller 1';
  
   $scope.sellerValue= function(sellerDetails){
    console.log("invoking sellerValue");
    console.log(sellerDetails);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <select style="width:250px; height:50px" ng-model="sellerDetails" ng-click="sellerValue(sellerDetails)">
                          <option >seller 1</option>
                          <option >seller 2</option>
                          <option >seller 3</option>
                        </select>
  </body>
```